# gulp compass creates an unwanted file instead of using only stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

This is my app-compass gulp task:

```
var compass = require('gulp-compass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('app-compass', function() {
    var stream = gulp.src('./app/styles/index.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            css: paths.css,
            sass: 'app/styles',
            image: 'app/assets/images',
            generated_images_path: paths.images
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css));
});
```

As part of compass, an index.css file created. This is an unwanted operation. I only want the data on the stream without write it to a file. Tomorrow I might change the destination and I'll have to change also the `css` property of compass, for example.
Is there a way where I can tell compass not to create a css file and only pass it via the stream?

Comment: What is 'compass'? please add all the npm requires. (I assume it is gulp-compass)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `compass` and `gulp.dest` are both creating the `.css` file. Try removing `.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css))` and ensuring the `css` property of the `compass` configuration object points to the desired destination location.

#### Updated Code from Original Poster

```
gulp.task('app-compass', function() {
    var stream = gulp.src('./app/styles/index.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            css: paths.css,
            sass: 'app/styles',
            image: 'app/assets/images',
            generated_images_path: paths.images
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer());
});
```

Comment: I had a similar issue of gulp making two folders and files. I added the css property to the object and removed the .pipe(gulp.dest()) method and it's working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `css: paths.css,` in the compass config. Otherwise compass thinks it should generate a css directly.

```
var compass = require('gulp-compass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('app-compass', function() {
    var stream = gulp.src('./app/styles/index.scss')
        .pipe(compass({

            sass: 'app/styles',
            image: 'app/assets/images',
            generated_images_path: paths.images
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css));
});
```

**EDIT:**

I just ran it again, and indeed, it created the css directory in the root. I had only checked the app/css… Sorry, it looks like the documentation says that it is not possible for the ruby compass to work that way:

> Please make sure to add css and sass options with the same value in
>   config.rb since compass can't output css result directly.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compass

Unfortunately, I don't see a good solution at the moment. Fortunately, the extra file generation wont kill your performance.

Or you could have a look at Bourbon, which is pretty similar to Compass and better integrated into the node environment (because it is only the mixins without a special compiler of its own):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bourbon

Comment: It doesn't work. The css option has default of '/css'

Comment: Do you have any other settings anywhere? Or are you using an old version of gulp-compass? Because I tried it in a test system and it worked.

Comment: I don't have other settings. This is a new project I've started... Can you post your example?

Comment: In the code you fixed, I think that gulp.dest(paths.css) overrides compass's file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
var compass = require('gulp-compass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');

gulp.task('app-compass', function() {
    var stream = gulp.src('./app/styles/index.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            css: paths.css,
            sass: 'app/styles',
            image: 'app/assets/images',
            generated_images_path: paths.images
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(clean())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css));
});
```

Comment: I don't see how clean can help here.

Comment: @Naor it would remove the unwanted file?