# gulp.dest failed overriding existent files

Tags: gulp, gulp-compass

I have this simple `gulp` task to process `.scss` files:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    compass = require('gulp-compass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    reload = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('app/scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(compass({
            config_file: './config.rb',
            css: 'app/css',
            sass: 'app/scss',
            require: ['susy', 'breakpoint']
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});
```

My problem is that when there is already an `app/css/style.css`, it won't be overridden by running task `gulp css`.

As per https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs#destfolder-opt, `gulp.dest` should by default override the files in the destination folder. And I have another `gulp` task for uglify `js`, the overriding in which works well.

Could someone give me some hint on why this is happening?

Comment: You did everything right. The Problem here seems to be gulp-compass itself. Does the `config.rb` file exist in your project?

Comment: Yes, it does.

   `require 'susy'`
    `require 'breakpoint'`

    `project_type = :stand_alone`
    `http_path = "/"`
    `sass_dir = "app/scss"`
    `css_dir = "app/css"`
    `images_dir = "app/images"`
    `fonts_dir = "app/fonts"`
    `javascript_dir = "app/js"`
    `line_comments = true`
    `preferred_syntax = :scss`
    `output_style = :compressed`
    `relative_assets = true`

Actually, everything works except that `gulp` doesn't override the existent file in the destination folder.

Comment: I have a similar setup except that I'll rather use `gulp-sass` instead of `gulp-compass` and everything works fine here. So the problem isn't `gulp.dest` for sure. Maybe this discussion gives you some hints on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383740/gulp-compass-creates-an-unwanted-file-instead-of-using-only-stream